# python sqlalchemy mysql use parameter as keyword

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, parameters, sqlalchemy

I am having trouble getting passed parameters in sqlalchemy to act as columns or tables.

For example, I'd like to select whatever column I pass as a parameter

```py
result = connection.execute(
    text(
        SELECT :selected_column FROM example_table
    ),
    **{'selected_column': 'col1'}
).fetchall()
```

But this ends up returning just the string version of the column name. How can I dynamically pass columns to the select statement?

Answer (score 0):

Parameters are treated as if they are literal values. Parameters are not just string-substitution.

If you want to make a dynamic query that selects a column named by a Python variable, you have to expand that variable in the query string *before* that string is passed to the database connector.

Example:

```
mycol = 'col1'

result = connection.execute(
    f"""
        SELECT `{mycol}` FROM example_table
    """).fetchall()
```

It's a good idea to delimit the column name in back-ticks, just in case the name contains special characters or is an SQL reserved keyword. Also it's up to you to make sure the name doesn't contain a back-tick character, or else you'll end up with imbalanced back-ticks.

These same rules apply if you combine Python variables with the query for any part that isn't normally a string literal or a numeric literal. E.g. table identifiers, keywords, expressions, etc.

Comment: What about sql injection? This solution leaves that open

Comment: Right — it's up to you to make sure the content of your Python variable doesn't have anything that could cause a problem. Don't use any untrusted input from users, or from files, or a web service, or even data you get out of the database.

Comment: I’m using this as part of a private api, so I guess I could validate the parameter before executing